# How to append a String to an array List ,when merging two Array lists in android?

Tags: android, arrays

I have two array lists A{a,b,c,} and B{c,d,e,f}.And i am merging these two array lists into one using this line  of code.

```
A.addAll(B)
```

What i need is, i want to add a String , for eg "End of first arraList " ,and it must print the String after printing List A .How to do this in android?? Can anyone help ??

Comment: before A.addAll(B) add A.add("your string")

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: just add another entry of your string in arraylist if those are of String type after you merge both